# Laravel: Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python Python runtime state: preinitialized

Tags: python, php, laravel

I can try to run Python script in Laravel. I am using composer require symfony/process for this. Actually, I don't want to use `shell_exec()`. When I try to run it, an error is returned. In the command line, everything is okay. My python script is located in the public folder.

**My Controller:**

```
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

    public function plagiarismCheck() {
        $process = new Process(['C:/Program Files/Python39/python.exe', 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/www/abyss-hub/public/helloads.py']);
        $process->run();

        // executes after the command finishes
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        return $process->getOutput(); 
    }
```

**Python script:**

```
print('Hello Python')
```

**Error:**

```
The command ""C:/Program Files/Python39/python.exe" "C:/Users/User/Desktop/www/abyss-hub/public/helloads.py"" failed. 
Exit Code: 1(General error) 
Working directory: 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\www\abyss-hub\public 
Output: ================ Error
Output: ================ Fatal 
Python error: 
_Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python 
Python runtime state: preinitialized.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### You need to configure the process environment variables:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#setting-environment-variables-for-processes

```
$process = new Process(["python", $pathToFilePython, ...$yourArgs], env: [
  'SYSTEMROOT' => getenv('SYSTEMROOT'),
  'PATH' => getenv("PATH")
]);

$process->run();
$process->getOutput();
```

- PATH: To recognize the "**python** "command.
- SYSTEMROOT: OS dependencies for Python to work.