# 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in laravel app

Tags: python, laravel

i need help really.
i try to run python script in laravel .
here python.py

```
#!/C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe

print("Hello, World from Python!")
```

i insert python path on top (window env) .
and I call it from controller php.
i place python file in public folder .and using sympony

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\ExecutableFinder;

public function index(){

       $process = new Process(['python', public_path().'/python.py']); 
       $process->run();
         $process->getOutput();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
         dd($process->getErrorOutput());
           }
         else{
           dd($process);
         }

    
     }
```

but this process not success .

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,


operable program or batch file.
```

here python path in git bash

[image]

what wrong?
plz help me.

Comment: im not a php expert these days, however Process probably does not inherit your path or environment... try running `env` in your Process to see whats in it... it likely takes some optional params to define the environment vars ... or include full path to python3 binary (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#setting-environment-variables-for-processes)

Comment: In Windows, you can search for "edit environment variables for your account" and then add your python3 installation directory to the PATH variable.

Comment: @asultan904 his env is right somewhere... since he can run from otherplaces

Comment: maybe simply use full path to python in `Process()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:
[Laravel: Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python Python runtime state: preinitialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499290/laravel-fatal-python-error-py-hashrandomization-init-failed-to-get-random-nu)

Send in those extra args. So for your question it would be:

```
$process = new Process(['python', public_path().'/python.py'], 
    null,
    ['SYSTEMROOT' => getenv('SYSTEMROOT'), 'PATH' => getenv("PATH")]);
```

Basically I am just copy/pasting this from the other answer.